# Symbol not found linking a library

Tags: c++, symbols

I'm writing a simple game engine, and I have the EntityComponent.h file:

```
#ifndef Psycho2D_Core_EntityComponent_
#define Psycho2D_Core_EntityComponent_

#include <string>

namespace psycho2d{

    class EntityComponent{

    private:
        std::string m_name;

    public:
        EntityComponent(const std::string &name);

        virtual ~EntityComponent();

        const std::string& getName() const;

        virtual void initialize() = 0;

        virtual void loadProperties() = 0;      

        virtual void update() = 0;

        virtual void destroy() = 0;

    };

}

#endif
```

And the relative EntityComponent.cpp file:

```
#include "EntityComponent.h"
#include <string>

psycho2d::EntityComponent::EntityComponent(const std::string &name){
    this->m_name = name;
}

psycho2d::EntityComponent::~EntityComponent(){}

inline const std::string& psycho2d::EntityComponent::getName() const{
    return this->m_name;
}
```

These two file are part of a framework (I'm working on a Mac). They compile well.
The problem is when I write an executable that use the library.
I have created a sub-class of EntityComponent, and it compiles. But, if I call the getName() function, the linker tell me:

```
"psycho2d::EntityComponent::getName() const", referenced from:
_main in main.o
Symbol(s) not found
Collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What I can do?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you implemented all of the abstract virtual methods that you specified in your interface?

Comment: Might help if you include your compile/link commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the code for the inline function in the header file, if you want to reference it from multiple .cpp files.

Reference [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html#faq-9.7).

Answer (score 2):

An external linkage `inline` function must defined (as effectively the same) in every translation unit where it's used.

So either remove the `inline` from the definition, or place the definition in the header file.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

Your (slightly modified to include a subclass to text) code compiles fine on my machine (A Mac, too. GCC 4.2.1)

Try removing all .o-files and compile with a clean directory. If that fails too, I'd try to remove the inline-definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `inline` qualifier from your implementation.